# How do I "mv */* ./" in a Windows command shell?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, move

On a Windows machine, I've got about 50 subdirectories in the same directory, each with around 5 files in it. I want to get all 250-or-so files into one directory.

In a UNIX system, I'd just open a shell, type

```
mv */* ./
```

and be done with it.

I don't know how to do this in Windows. `move */* ./` doesn't work.

Comment: windows uses \ not / as a path separator, because Microsoft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command is to be entered in the Command Prompt when
the directory in question is the current:

```
for /r %i in (*.*) do move "%i" .
```

Note that overwriting files with the same name will fail.
Note also that it will move files from any depth, so do not use
this command if your folders have sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks!  That ... almost worked.  It worked when I put the last %i in quotes, as some of the names had spaces in them.  :)

Comment: I added the quotes to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This command can be used in batch file or CMD:

`forfiles /P . /S /M * /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE move @path %cd%"`

References: [Example of forfiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles#examples)

Note that overwriting files with the same name will overwrite it.